# (False) import error warning with global PyLint in virtual environment in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I use Visual Studio Code for coding in Python.
In my python file, I stated the following imports:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I created a virtual environment, installed all necessary packages with `pip install` inside the virtual environment and the python script runs fine.

In Visual Studio Code, I modified the settings to use PyLint which is installed on the global level (meaning the default python interpreter) so I don't need to install pylint in my virtual environment in order to avoid for it appearing in my `requirements.txt`. My `.vscode/settings.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/pazifik/.virtualenvs/fun-image-scraper/bin/python",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/pylint"
}
```

Visual Studio Code seems to pick up Pylint correctly, however in the "Problems" view it shows this:

```
Unable to import 'requests' pylint(importError) [3, 1]
Unable to import 'bs4' pylint(importError) [4, 1]
```

The reason is probably that the global installed PyLint cannot see the packages inside the virtual environment. The chosen Python interpreter in Visual Studio Code is the Python interpreter from the virtual environment.

How can I get rid of these (false) import errors in Visual Studio Code?

EDIT:
To better visualize my problem and settings, here some screenshots:

pip list of installed packages in virtual environment
[image: Interpreter and list of packages in virtual env]

pip show of `requests`package in virtual environment
[image: pip show of requests]

"Problems" view (however! the script runs fine as mentioned, just the errors displayed there are confusing hence my question)
[image: Problems view]

PyLint installed in global environment with default interpreter
[image: Pylint in default environment]

Comment: Maybe this problem has something to do with the interpretter selected by your VsCode, so try to Ctrl+Shift+P and chose the Python Intepreter for your virtual environment !

Comment: @Sanixdarker I have chosen the Python interpreter for my virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very sorry for my previous answer, I had modified the pylintArgs before, so I have not found out the problem.

You can add this in the settings.json:

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

And create a file named `.env` under the workspace folder, and add this in it:

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/pazifik/.virtualenvs/fun-image-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

**Explain:**

Although you have selected the virtual environment in the VSCode, and you can find the `PYTHONPATH` has been modified in the terminal, but the `pylint` did not route through the terminal, so it will not get the modified `PYTHONPATH`.

> When the terminal settings are used, PYTHONPATH affects any tools that
> are run within the terminal by a user, as well as any action the
> extension performs for a user that is routed through the terminal such
> as debugging. However, in this case when the extension is performing
> an action that isn't routed through the terminal, such as the use of a
> linter or formatter, then this setting will not have an effect on
> module look-up.
>
> When PYTHONPATH is set using an .env file, it will affect anything the
> extension does on your behalf and actions performed by the debugger,
> but it will not affect tools run in the terminal.

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable).

Comment: This seems to work, import errors are gone after a restart of VsCode. Is there any way to use wildcards for PYTHONPATH (could not find any documentation/examples in web) or do I have to explicitly set all virtual environments manually once?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it works well on my computer. Could you reconfirm which python interpreter you have selected, and where the python packages you have installed?

You can get which python interpreter you have used from the bottom-left of the VSCode or the environment name in the terminal:

[image]

The setting of `python.pythonPath` in the settings.json can not determine which python interpreter you are using.

And maybe you just installed the packages in the different environments, could you take the command of `pip show {packagename}` to check where the packages have been installed?

Comment: I have edited my question with some screenshots. Please take a look. Pylint is only  installed in global/default environment. The packages are only installed in the virtual environment.